# Azure Table Storage SDK - Can't Insert

Tags: c#, azure

I am working with [Azure Table Storage SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/5.0.3-preview) and I can read and delete entities fine but insert operations give me the following XmlException. Any ideas?

```
An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Here is my insert code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=myKey");
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("positions");
await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

var p = new PositionEntity("test", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(p);
var result = table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.Exception != null)
    {
        // read Exception here...
        var x = RequestResult.TranslateFromExceptionMessage(t.Exception.Message);
    }
});
```

Note: I am running on DNX 4.5.1.

**Edit:**

It turns out that my `PositionEntity` has a DateTimeOffset property that was not being set. It was not nullable and therefore was being instantiated with the default DateTimeOffset value. If I set the Date property manually before sending, the insert works properly.

```
var p = new PositionEntity("test", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
p.Date = DateTime.Now; // <-- This is required if default. Default value doesn't work!
```

Here is the raw response from Azure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code>OutOfRangeInput</code><message xml:lang="en-US">One of the request inputs is out of range. RequestId:eeb6ed0c-0002-001f-48f5-f64ea4000000 Time:2015-09-24T18:18:32.8854764Z</message></error>
```

Does anyone know why the default DateTimeOffset value ({01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM +00:00}) is not a valid value in Azure Table Storage?!?

Comment: Is it possible for you to trace the request/response through Fiddler or Browser developer tools and see what's sent across the wire? That will certainly help diagnosing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the supported DateTime range begins from 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D., UTC. The range ends at December 31, 9999.

FYI: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx) has provided the following table detailing the data ranges of the data types in Azure Table Storage: